# Explanatory model for zero-one inflated bimodal data with random effect and binary indepentent variable

Tags: regression, mixed-model, effect-size, zero-inflation, beta-regression

I'm trying to evaluate the influence of a single binary explanatory variable on a 0-1 scale response, with one grouping factor. The response variable is generally 0-1 inflated. The simplest solution would be to collapse the data to a 2x2 contingency table, however, the magnitude of 0-1 inflation generally seems to depend on the grouping factor, therefore I'd prefer to include its random effect in a model. I also would prefer to keep the response continuous - its conditional variance is quite relevant.

As the data violates assumptions of linear regression, I've tried to model it in R glmmTMB with beta regression with a logit link. DHARMa plots hint that it's not a particularly good fit, and the model seems to "squish" the data towards a global mean, therefore possibly lowering the effect size of the explanatory variable, which I'm particularly interested in.

I have considered fitting separate models for 0-1 response and the remaining variance, however, I'm not really sure how to do this kind of compound analysis.

I'd be grateful for any help with moving forward. I attach the plot of data by grouping factor. Only groups with N>25 were considered for modeling.

[image]